# Is there a method to fetch individual users added to Confluence space

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api

I want to retrieve all the individual users mapped to a Confluence space along with the permission granted to them. Is there a method to achieve the same via REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Right now there is no way to get permission info on a space using the REST API.
An option would be to write your own Rest Service (using the Atlassian API diretly or via Scriptrunner) and query that.
A 2nd option, yet a bit cumbersome would be to call the permissions page of the space admin, and use webscraping to get the users and groups, and then expand the groups to get all users in these groups.

Please keep in mind that you might get all confluence users for some spaces which might cause a problem.

Why do you need this information? Maybe there is another way to solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
We are performing UAR in Confluence, this includes fetching users and the permission granted to each user in a particular space (either via being a part of a group or by being added individually) We have over 1500+ spaces, hence looking at automating the process.

Comment: Do you have ScriptRunner for Confluence? Or would it be an option to install it? The actual task is pretty straight forward using the java API.

Comment: Yes we do have ScriptRunner plugin installed. Could you please throw some light on how this can be done via JAVA API